# What returns Livedata in Android Room database if no object meet the condition?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

//For example:

```
@Query("SELECT max(date(date_of) FROM table_1 WHERE fk_id = :ID GROUP BY pk_id")
LiveData<List<SomeClass>> getMaxDate(int ID);
```

What happens if there is no such ID ? Is Livedata than returning NULL ?

Comment: That SQL should not compile (unbalanced parentheses). But, I would expect the `LiveData` to emit an empty `List`.

Comment: Yea, empty list it is